# How to combine Faceted Search with 'browsing' action?

Tags: website-design, usability, filter, search-results, faceted-search

I don't have a UX background, so forgive me if I am missing something. I am working on a [small demo](http://moviesdb.herokuapp.com/#), to explore browsing a list of items (movies) combined with faceted search.

I was wondering what the options for interaction are when a new user comes to this page looking for an item:

- In order to give access to movies quickly, I was thinking to have a general 'genres filter' to the left. When a user clicks on it, she can then further refine the search.
- If a user wants to compare movies from different genres, it would be necessary to allow multiple categories to be selected.
- Apart from this, some search would need to help the user to find a movie given certain criteria.

Now, I was wondering:

- Would it be good to provide faceted search from the start?
- How would the user expect to interact with facets?
- What data of facets should be displayed? When?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by faceted search you mean allowing multiple filters, it is a good idea to do that in your scenario.

In your demo you have filtering based on genre and the sub-filtering based on ratings. I would suggest converting it into checkboxes and **separating the filters**:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHSrl1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: thanks for your feedback. the mockup makes it very clear. ok, I'll rewrite some parts of the UI.

Comment: new demo here: http://moviesdb.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @poseid Couple things: If you use > in the genres, it means it's a menu item of sort. Replace that with a check-box. Also, in the filtering by rating, rather than limiting by 5,4,3,2,1 you should make it 5, 4 or higher, 3 or higher, 2 or higher, 1 or higher.